# occurrence - TreeMap

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap

I have a treemap containing occurrence of words like this ...

```
TreeMap <String,Integer> occurrence = new TreeMap <String,Integer>();
```

String = Word

Integer = amount of occurrence.

How would I get the maximum occurrence - integer and then get the String mapped to the highest occurrence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to iterate through the map and search for it linearly. The `TreeMap` is sorted on the keys, not the values.

Comment: ... or if you find yourself in need to find something by its frequency often, you ought to change your data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.max` against the Map's keyset with a custom comparator to get the largest entry:

```
String highestOccurrence = Collections.max(occurrence.keySet(), 
  new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
       return occurrence.get(a).compareTo(occurrence.get(b));
    }
});
```

This encapsulates the iteration itself for you but behind the scenes it will still be a linear search.

Comment: @Thomas: No I mean the keyset.  @unleashed: The comparator works by taking the two String keys, but instead of comparing them it gets the corresponding occurrence count ( `Integer`) from your existing `Map` and returns the result of comparing those values.